# How to filter number in cell

Tags: matlab

I have a cell `v { '$100' '100' 'text' 'word' }` and, I want filter this cell according to below basic rule. How can I manage this even if cell size is bigger than 1000, in a time efficient way?

Rule:

- If number start with `$` then filter that entry and write `price` keyword
- If it is start with nothing, filter it and then write `number` in its place

Result will be
 {'price' 'number'  'text' 'word' }

Comment: You say you want a time efficient way, but what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the first character of each cell's string with [`strncmp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html) (in case the string is empty), and replace the selected cells using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) :

```
v = { '$100' '100' 'text' 'word' }; %// data

v( cellfun( @(c) strncmp(c,'$',1), v) ) = {'price'};
v( cellfun( @(c) any(strncmp(c,{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'},1)), v) ) = {'number'}
```